# What is the use in & and && operator in the following program?

Tags: c

I saw the following code in one website to check odd or even number without using "if". But, I  am not able to understand the coding and how it works. Please, can you explain the functional part of the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int no;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    (no & 1 && printf("odd")) || printf("even");
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: [`bitwise AND`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: The output of `printf` should give you a hint.

Comment: @alk I didn't mean the return value of `printf`, I mean the output content, i.e, `"odd"` and `"even"`.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh! thanks guys. I can now understand the shortcircuit behaviour of operators.

Comment: @user3289137 One think you will notice same symbol can be use for different operations `&` can be address of operator or a bitwise OR operator It depends in which syntax it appears,  `&` symbol in Syntax `&a`   is address of *unary* operator And In expression `a & b`. `&` is bitwise AND *binary* operator. Similarly you can observer   the difference for `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `&no`, address operator

   ```
   scanf("%d",&no);
   ```

   This `&no` means the address of the variable `no`. It is used to have `scanf()` put the result there.
2. `&`, bitwise AND

   no & 1

   This is the value of `no`, bitwise `AND`ed with the value 1. Essentially, this gives the value of the lowest bit. If that bit is set, the value is odd, otherwise even.
3. `&&` and `||`, short-circuit operators

   ```
   ((expression from above) && printf("odd")) || printf("even");
   ```

This expression is supposed to output `odd` if the value is odd and `even` if the value is even.

`&&` and `||` are so-called "short-circuit operators". So the following happens:

- If the expression is false (== 0), the first part evaluates to `(0 && ...)`, which evaluates to 0 without evaluating the 2nd part. So we have `0 || printf("even")`, which is equivalent to `printf("even")`.
- If, however, the expression is true (!= 0), the first part evaluates to `(1 && ...)`, where `1 &&` is redundant. So essentially you have `printf("odd") || printf("even")`. This relies on `printf("odd")` returning a nonzero value, so that `printf("even")` is suppressed.

Thus, better solutions would be

```
(no & 1) ? printf("odd") : printf("even");
printf((no & 1) ? "odd" : "even");
if (no & 1) {
    printf("odd");
} else {
    printf("even");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`&` is used for bit-wise AND and `&&` is used for logical AND.

Now the logic is that **a number is even if its least significant bit is `0` and is odd if LSB is `1`**.
`(no & 1)` checks whether LSB is `0` or `1`, i.e, by anding it will give `0` if LSB is `0` and `1` if LSB is `1`.
If it is `0` then the right expression of `&&` is not evaluated because of the short circuit behavior of the operator and hence right sub-expression of `||` prints `"even"`. If `no & 1` is `1` then right sub-expression of `&&` is evaluated and prints `"odd"`.

Answer (score 4):

`no & 1` gets the least significant bit of `no`. Thus, `no & 1` gets 1 if `no` is odd.

If `no & 1 == 0`, then the right hand side of `&&` is skipped, `(no & 1 && printf("odd"))` is evaluated as FALSE, and `printf("even")` is evaluated.

If `no & 1 != 0`, then the right hand side of `&&` is evaluated and prints `"odd"` on console. `(no & 1 && printf("odd"))` is evaluated as TRUE if the `printf()` successes, and then the right hand side of `||` is skipped.

Answer (score 3):

The `no & 1` is a bitwise `AND`. The result of that operation will be `0` if `no` is even and `1` if `no` is odd.  This is because only the least significant bit of `1` is set.

The `&&` in `(no & 1 && printf("odd"))` is a boolean `AND`, and the expression relies on the short-circuit evaluation of that operator.  If `no & 1` evaluates to `false` (when `no` is even), the statement will not print. When `no & 1` evaluates to `true` (when `no` is odd), the `printf("odd")` statement will be evaluated.

It's in the case where `no & 1` evaluates to `false` that then entire `&&` expression evaluates to `false` and the second `printf` statement is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to understand `(no & 1 && printf("odd")) || printf("even");`.

- `&` means **bitwise and** so `no & 1` means get first bit from 1.
- `&&` means **logical and** but it uses short circuit so it won't evaluate second expression if first is *true*.
- `||` means **logical or** but it uses short circuit so it won't evaluate second expression if first is *false*.

So it will print **odd** if `(no & 1) == 1` or, in other words, if `no % 2 == 1`; else it will evaluate the last printf so it will print **even**.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first bit of "no" and if 0 skip && operator and proceed to evaluate printf("even"). If 1, go evaluate printf("odd")

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is logical and.
true `&&` true is true and everything else is false.
`&` is bitwise and.

It can be explained as binary:
Code:

```
  00000110
& 00000100
----------------
  00000100
================
```

For more information : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial...operators.html
Read about other bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

&no is the address of variable no.
&& is the logical AND.
|| is OR.

Comment: Oh, no, it's `no & 1`, not `&no`.

Comment: @YuHao We as well have a `&no`, in the line above.

Comment: @glglgl Oh, yes, I must have skipped that line in my head automatically.